# Доступ к логам контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Есть джава приложение, соответственно оно закидывается в докер контейнер.

У приложения есть логи, на которые хотелось бы натравить filebeat.

Запустить эти 2 сервиса я могу, но как сделать так чтобы, они видели друг друга (точнее, чтобы filebeat видел логи). Как я понимаю нужно запустить их в одном контейнере. И как это сделать?

Мои предположения заключаются в том чтобы установить *nix систему и там уже собирать, но хотелось бы что-то попроще.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно логи пробрасывают наружу докер контейнера т.е на хостовую машину на которой запущен докер. Для сохранности самих логов в первую очередь. Так вот, примонтируй в сервисе, в котором ранится java, volume наружу, если запускаете через docker-compose или запускай контейнер с параметрами volume если запускаете по отдельности каждый контейнер.Тот же volume монтируй и во второй свой сервис. И делай с этими логами что угодно. Примерный docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  java-app:
    ...
    volumes:
     - .host-directory:/java-app/logs

  log-service:
    volumes:
      - .host-directory:/container/dir
```